# Can't share folder from Ubuntu 22.04 to Windows 10

Tags: 22.04, samba, sharing

I am trying to share a folder called `prueba`  from a machine with Ubuntu 22.04 to a Windows 10 system.  I already installed samba, and I shared the folder in Ubuntu, but when I'm trying to access it from Windows I get the error `Windows cannot access \\192.168.1.5\prueba`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You didn't supply enough information to answer the question. Please edit your post and add the output of these commands: `testparm -s` `net usershare info --long`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Any additional details that you can offer would be helpful -- Exactly *how* did you share the folder?  What configuration might be in place?  Etc.  The community loves to help out whenever possible, but they'll probably need a bit more information in order to give you good suggestions.  Thanks!